# DynamoDB error when update Date: Unsupported type passed: ... Pass options.convertClassInstanceToMap=true to marshall typeof object as map attribute

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

When I would like to insert new document into DynamoDB database, Date type property `date` is inserted without any problem.

```
 table.create("User", {
     accountName: "johndoe",
     email: "test@test74.test",
     date: new Date(), // Date is inserted without any problem
     username: "johndoe",
     firstName: "John",
     lastName: "Doe"

 }).then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```

But later, when I would like to update the document `date` property, I will get the following error:

```
Error: Unsupported type passed: Mon Oct 31 2022 16:15:25 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time).
Pass options.convertClassInstanceToMap=true to marshall typeof object as map attribute.
```

DynamoDB update code:

```
table.update("User", {pk: "johndoe"}, {
    set: {
        date: new Date()
    }
}).catch(console.error)
```

Thanks a lot for each help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with ISO format

```js
table.update("User", {pk: "johndoe"}, {
    set: {
        date: new Date().toISOString()
    }
}).catch(console.error)
```

Also using Date as a partition key is not a good idea :)

Comment: I already tried it, but It not works :-(, I get the following error: err: ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema, probably, because string<=>Date types are not matches.

Comment: From the docs -> Date (as ISO_8601 millisecond-precision string, shifted to UTC).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html

It seems you have to provide the timestamp

Comment: I tried new getTime(), toISOString(), toUTCString(), toDateString(), toString() and not works, still the same error: ValidationException

Comment: ...and in create method, I will set only date: new Date() and It works. In update, works nothing. I dont understand, what Im doying wrong... :-(

Comment: "The provided key element does not match the schema" means that the name of the key column is not that. Where are you setting the partition key to be called ''pk" it it "accountName"?

Comment: EDIT: I only manually created table for the testing and sets pk as primary key without sort key. In schema I have primary: {hash:'pk'} And when I will set the firstName(string) in same update, it works. With date field, I get error.

Comment: you had truth, I don't know, where was the problem, because I nothing changed, but now the new Date().toISOString(); works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `convertClassInstanceToMap` to `true` in the marshalling option resolved the issue (as given in the error description).

e.g.

```js
import { DynamoDB } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb'
import { DynamoDBDocument } from '@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb'

const marshallOptions = {
  // Whether to automatically convert empty strings, blobs, and sets to `null`.
  // convertEmptyValues: false, // false, by default.
  // Whether to remove undefined values while marshalling.
  removeUndefinedValues: true, // false, by default.
  // Whether to convert typeof object to map attribute.
  convertClassInstanceToMap: true // false, by default. <---- Set this flag
}

const unmarshallOptions = {
  // Whether to return numbers as a string instead of converting them to native JavaScript numbers.
  // wrapNumbers: false, // false, by default.
}

const translateConfig = { marshallOptions, unmarshallOptions }

// const dynamodb = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(new DynamoDBClient(), translateConfig)
const dynamodb = DynamoDBDocument.from(new DynamoDB(), translateConfig)
```